# Cannot connect to sql database using abp framework in asp .net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, database-connection, aspnetboilerplate

I am working in web api project with DDD architecture in asp .net core using aspnetboilerplate, the process is just like the sample (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core), but it did't work(dbContextOptions.IsConfigured = false)

exception in connection:

> "Value cannot be null.Parameter name:
>   unitOfWork"

Stratup class:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddAbpDbContext<SampleDBContext>(options =>
    {
       DBContextOptionsConfigurer.Configure(options.DbContextOptions,    options.ConnectionString);
});
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        return services.AddAbp<ApiModule>();
    }
```

DBContextOptionsConfigurer class:

```
public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleDBContext> dbContextOptions,string connectionString)
    {
    //dbContextOptions.IsConfigured = false,ConnectionStrings is in appsettings.json
        dbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
```

Context class:

```
public class SampleDBContext : AbpDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Language> Language { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewsLetter> NewsLetter { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostCategory> PostCategory { get; set; }

    public SampleDBContext(DbContextOptions<SampleDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Api Module class:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(ApplicationModule),
    typeof(EntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpAspNetCoreModule))]
public class ApiModule : AbpModule
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;

    public ApiModule(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _appConfiguration = AppSetting.Get(env.ContentRootPath, env.EnvironmentName);
    }
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.DefaultNameOrConnectionString = _appConfiguration.GetConnectionString(Keys.ConnectionStringName);
        Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore().CreateControllersForAppServices(typeof(ApplicationModule).Assembly, moduleName: "app", useConventionalHttpVerbs: true);
    }
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(ApiModule).GetAssembly());
    }
}
```

I would be appreciated if you could help me in this area. Which step is wrong?

Comment: You have to put break points into the code and determine which methods are getting executed and which are not getting executed.  I usually like stepping through the code at least once to make sure each instruction is getting executed.  Right not there are thousands of reasons the code may not work and we do not have any clue where the actual problem is located.

Comment: what's the exception logged on the host?